# Why aren't SPL token TXs included in getSignaturesForAddress(...)?

Tags: transactions, send-transaction, spl, api, usdc

For instance:
https://solscan.io/account/2LshMLoR8QJkuAv7m6xAs4tYaS5XTfF4Yame21f1Ls9o

Currently, there're 6 TXs on the main tab.

On the SPL Transfers tab the most recent TX with USDC ($1100) was made a few hours ago:

https://solscan.io/tx/3bceqvBQxKzRxrvwRAaecRA4EgsrDAxqkNYprVN96DfRnhTLWsLQGwi46hJQ63d3Bt8jAna9XuNKiusgj6CyuyZb

However, the list of the TXs on the main tab doesn't include that one at all. Moreover, a request to the API `getSignaturesForAddress(...)` won't include that TX with USDC either! But I need it.  Why hasn't it been included?

What should I do then? How to make the API call include such SPL TXs too?

Or how else obtain them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this said transaction is not included in the `getSignaturesForAddress()` because it is called with the wallet address, and the wallet address is not an account included in this transaction (spl transfer).

If you want to get the 4 usdc transactions of this wallet, you have to use `getSignaturesForAddress()` with the associated token account address like this : `getSignaturesForAddress(BqtewRVV4LsGvgfnjRRwzXdnYBbJCXs9C3mTzeJns7uz)`